# django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: django, python-3.x, powershell, anaconda, powershell-2.0

I have installed Django on my computer with the help of the anaconda and used command

```
conda install -c anaconda django
```

for the same. Now when I was supposed to work on Django so I typed

```
django -admin --version
```

in order to get information about it's version, what I found was

> 'django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command

as it's output.

I am referring to this  [online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&index=1&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK)

Comment: It sounds like `.py` or `python` is not registered as an extension or in your PATH.

Comment: Yes, the problem has been solved by referring to the link by @Capricorn Thanks a Lot. I don't know how to mark solved to this question, please help me to do so and thanks in advance.